Implement google login with django
I have a django application in which I want to deploy google login auth. My frontend framework is flutter. After login with flutter in to the google, it sends auth_code received from google to the django backend. This is how I implement my login
google_auth_request = HttpRequestManager()


class GoogleAuth:
    def __init__(self, code):
        self.code = code

    def get_access_token(self, code: str, redirect_uri: str) -> str:
        data = {
            "code": code,
            "client_id": config.settings.constants.GOOGLE_AUTH_CONFIG["GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID"],
            "client_secret": config.settings.constants.GOOGLE_AUTH_CONFIG["GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET"],
            "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        }

        response = google_auth_request.post(
            config.settings.constants.GOOGLE_AUTH_CONFIG["GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN_OBTAIN_URL"], data=data
        )
        if not response.ok:
            log.error("Response.json() for get access_token")
            log.error(response.json())
            print(response.json(), flush=True)
            raise ValidationError("Could not get access token from Google.")

        access_token = response.json()["access_token"]

        return access_token

    def get_user_info(self, access_token: str) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        response = google_auth_request.get(
            config.settings.constants.GOOGLE_AUTH_CONFIG["GOOGLE_USER_INFO_URL"], params={"access_token": access_token}
        )

        if not response.ok:
            log.error(f"google auth response data: {response.data}")
            print(response.json(), flush=True)
            raise Exception("google service is unavailable")

        return response.json()

    def login(self):
        domain = config.settings.constants.GOOGLE_AUTH_CONFIG["GOOGLE_OAUTH2_API_URL"]
        redirect_uri = f"{domain}/api/auth/v1/login/google/"

        access_token = self.get_access_token(code=self.code, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
        user_data = self.get_user_info(access_token)
        # Creates user in DB if first time login
        query = EtloUser.objects.filter(email=user_data["email"])
        if not query.exists():
            EtloUser.objects.create(
                email=user_data["email"],
                first_name=user_data.get("given_name"),
                last_name=user_data.get("family_name"),
            )

        profile_data = {
            "email": user_data["email"],
            "first_name": user_data.get("given_name"),
            "last_name": user_data.get("family_name"),
        }
        return profile_data

And this is its view
@extend_schema(request=GoogleAuthSerializer, responses={200: OutputCredentialSerializer})
class GoogleAuthView(APIView):
    throttle_scope = "auth"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        auth_serializer = GoogleAuthSerializer(data=request.data)
        auth_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        validated_data = auth_serializer.validated_data

        if validated_data["error"] or not validated_data["code"]:
            params = urlencode({"error": validated_data["error"]})
            return redirect(f"{config.settings.constants.GOOGLE_AUTH_CONFIG['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_LOGIN_URL']}?{params}")
        google_auth_service = GoogleAuth(validated_data["code"])
        user_profile = google_auth_service.login()

        auth_backend = EtloGoogleAuthenticationBackend(user_profile["email"])
        user = auth_backend.authenticate_credentials()
        tokens = auth_backend.get_user_tokens_data(user)
        return Response(tokens, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

But when flutter sends auth_code to the django, the line print(response.json(), flush=True) prints out: {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'}
When I read some threads I see that they put the details in params (postman) not the body. This is also the curl request:
curl --location --request POST 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?client_id=******-c4hrkmu0sfc1t3se6ni5g44aacg81iia.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=******-0lkcEi489FxaLzUwRGyF5MmAgE3T&code=******InQyhphLF2Cjjx75fCiiTCAVRtiZ3fNrUdwNXpwTSH0_-Vbrzl4VrKSQ&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fetlo-firebase.firebaseapp.com%2F__%2Fauth%2Fhandler&grant_type=authorization_code'

And this is the response which I get in postman:
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}


Your curl request is malformed, you cannot pass the oauth info as query parameters.
According to the docs:

invalid_grant
The supplied authorization code is invalid or in the wrong format. Request a new code by restarting the OAuth process to prompt the user for consent again.

And here's the correct format:

POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code

Which translates into curl as follows:
curl -X POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token \
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     -d "code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7" \
     -d "client_id=your_client_id" \
     -d "client_secret=your_client_secret" \
     -d "redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code" \
     -d "grant_type=authorization_code"

As for your Python code, it might be as simple as missing the Content-Type header that the docs specify.
Assuming HttpRequestManager is requests-compliant:
[...]
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = google_auth_request.post(config.settings.constants.GOOGLE_AUTH_CONFIG["GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN_OBTAIN_URL"], 
    data=data,
    headers=headers
)

